# How can i place the figure caption next to the figure in quarto pdf format?

Tags: r, quarto

How can I use side captions in Quarto PDF?

Will `fig-cap-location: margin` give me the desired result in pdf format?
I have tried putting it the header but this will be applied to all figures, however, I would like to specify it for each figure separately.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of using the quarto or latex syntax, use knitr to include the picture and put the cap-location argument in the chunk options like this:

````
```{r}
#| echo: false
#| fig-cap: My Picture
#| cap-location: margin

knitr::include_graphics("path/to/picture")
```
````

**Edit (10/14/2023)**

The problem we are running into is that LaTeX/Quarto is reserving space specifically for the margin across the document. So we need to convince our text to specifically infringe into the margin. This is definitely a hack solution (and not super convenient), but it is an option.

````
---
format: pdf
---

:::{.column-screen-inset-right}

This is some text to span across the page in order to see how the margins change in relation to the other text.

:::

```{r}
#| echo: false
#| fig-cap: My Picture
#| cap-location: margin

knitr::include_graphics("path/to/picture")
```

:::{.column-screen-inset-right}

This is some more text to span across the page in order to see how the margins change in relation to the other text.

:::
````

Comment: Either I am doing something wrong or this does not work as intended. It does not just put the figure caption beside the figure, but it introduces a whole new column to place the margin, which is extended over the whole document.

Comment: I provided an edited solution - try that

Comment: Unfortunately, it's the same result as before. Does it work for you?  After reinstalling the newest version of R, quarto and tinytex, at least I can use the latex syntax without any errors.  But this ruins the whole point of Quarto if such basic writing features aren't supported. I guess, the visual editor also becomes useless and you can't export it as HTML anymore... But thank you for your effort, it works in HTML but not in PDF format, maybe this is because of my  documentclass: scrreprt.

Comment: You're right - it may be a broader problem related to LaTeX article class and page format. I found that Rmarkdown and Quarto have always been kinder to HTML with compatibility for certain options.

Answer (score 1):

including this in the yaml file:

```
   include-in-header:
          text: |
            \usepackage{sidecap}
```

you call the figure with latex but give it a caption and label for cross-reference in quarto

````
  ::: {#fig-1 fig-env="SCfigure"}
    ```{=latex}
    \includegraphics[width=0.6\textwidth]{pic.png} 
    ```
    caption
    :::
````

and then you can crossref it as usual by

```
See @fig-1
```

super stupid but it is what it is ...